# Simultaneous equations in non-Euclidean space?

Tags: systems-of-equations, noneuclidean-geometry

As I recall, one visualizes equations as lines or planes in Euclidean space and the solutions are intersections among these lines, planes or higher-dimensional equivalents.

Is there some use to visualizing simultaneous equations as being collections of objects in non-Euclidean space? I realize this may be nonsense since searching this has yielded nothing so far.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "non-Euclidean space" but you may be interested in reading about algebraic geometry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: That looks sort of like what I was thinking of. But isn't non-Euclidean space just space in which non-Euclidean geometry holds, like shortest distance is not a straight line or some other characteristics? https://study.com/academy/lesson/differences-between-euclidean-non-euclidean-geometry.html#:~:text=surface%20is%20curved.-,Euclidean%20vs.,geometry%20may%20be%20more%20useful.

Comment: It could mean a lot of different things. If you're interested in distances then you want Riemannian geometry but it's less common to study systems of equations in that setting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_geometry